# cuDNN launch failure (tensorflow-gpu/CUDA)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, cudnn

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cuDNN launch failure : input shape ([202027,64,1,1])
     [[Node: bn_fm_1/FusedBatchNorm = FusedBatchNorm[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", epsilon=0.001, is_training=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](bn_fm_1/FusedBatchNorm-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, bn_fm/gamma/read, bn_fm/beta/read, bn_fm/moving_mean/read, bn_fm/moving_variance/read)]]
     [[Node: AddN/_31 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_202_AddN", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NeuralFM.py", line 350, in <module>
    model.train(data.Train_data, data.Validation_data, data.Test_data)
  File "NeuralFM.py", line 266, in train
    init_train = self.evaluate(Train_data)
  File "NeuralFM.py", line 311, in evaluate
    predictions = self.sess.run((self.out), feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cuDNN launch failure : input shape ([202027,64,1,1])
     [[Node: bn_fm_1/FusedBatchNorm = FusedBatchNorm[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", epsilon=0.001, is_training=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](bn_fm_1/FusedBatchNorm-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, bn_fm/gamma/read, bn_fm/beta/read, bn_fm/moving_mean/read, bn_fm/moving_variance/read)]]
     [[Node: AddN/_31 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_202_AddN", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'bn_fm_1/FusedBatchNorm', defined at:
  File "NeuralFM.py", line 349, in <module>
    model = NeuralFM(data.features_M, args.hidden_factor, eval(args.layers), args.loss_type, args.pretrain, args.epoch, args.batch_size, args.lr, args.lamda, eval(args.keep_prob), args.optimizer, args.batch_norm, activation_function, args.verbose, args.early_stop)
  File "NeuralFM.py", line 89, in __init__
    self._init_graph()
  File "NeuralFM.py", line 123, in _init_graph
    self.FM = self.batch_norm_layer(self.FM, train_phase=self.train_phase, scope_bn='bn_fm')
  File "NeuralFM.py", line 224, in batch_norm_layer
    is_training=False, reuse=True, trainable=True, scope=scope_bn)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 183, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 596, in batch_norm
    scope=scope)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 382, in _fused_batch_norm
    is_training, _fused_batch_norm_training, _fused_batch_norm_inference)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/utils.py", line 214, in smart_cond
    return static_cond(pred_value, fn1, fn2)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/utils.py", line 194, in static_cond
    return fn2()
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 379, in _fused_batch_norm_inference
    data_format=data_format)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 906, in fused_batch_norm
    name=name)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 3465, in _fused_batch_norm
    is_training=is_training, name=name)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InternalError (see above for traceback): cuDNN launch failure : input shape ([202027,64,1,1])
     [[Node: bn_fm_1/FusedBatchNorm = FusedBatchNorm[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", epsilon=0.001, is_training=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](bn_fm_1/FusedBatchNorm-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, bn_fm/gamma/read, bn_fm/beta/read, bn_fm/moving_mean/read, bn_fm/moving_variance/read)]]
     [[Node: AddN/_31 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_202_AddN", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I keep getting this error, I've tried everything from downgrading CUDA, cuDNN, and tensorflow-gpu.

I'm currently on CUDA 9.0, cuDNN v7.4.2 for CUDA 9.0, tensorflow-gpu 1.9 and nothing I do seems to help. I'm running out of ideas, I've got every dependency I could imagine.

I'm trying to run this:
https://github.com/hexiangnan/neural_factorization_machine

**EDIT:** I have a feeling this is connected to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8090 but as I'm a little new to all this, I'm not sure if I'm right or how to address this.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but I would imagine for those who do it's be helpful if you added what gpu, cpu and amount of RAM you have

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error. The reason for mine is that my GPU does not have enough memory for the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably a few of years late to be of any help Alex but I've come up on this issue when on Windows with a specific GPU. Don't ask me why but adding

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '/gpu:0'
```

if you have a single GPU works for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following in the script.

```
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
```

Comment: Are you sure that is "in the script" the part of the code?